# SMC vs 10-32 Coaxial Connector

Tags: rf, connector, adapter

I have a [393B04 PCB](http://www.pcb.com/products/model/393b04) [specs](http://www.pcb.com/contentstore/docs/PCB_Corporate/Vibration/Products/Manuals/393B04.pdf) and a [drawing](http://www.pcb.com/contentstore/docs/PCB_Corporate/Vibration/Products/Drawing/PDF/14129-C.pdf) denoting a "10-32 UNF 2A Coaxial Electrical Connector".

[image]

This is the same than a SMC Connector?. Can i purchase an standard SMC connector which supposedly fits the 10-32 UNF 2A thread?, or i must purchase 10-32 coaxial connectors?

Edit:

- The spec only focus on the thread, not on the electrical connector. I guess this is for commercial purposes, for selling built expensive cable,
- As definitions: jack: thread outside, plug: thread inside, male: a pin contact, female: a covering contact,
- As indicated, **clearly** this is not a regular SMC connector, which is a male jack,
- Unless i should seek for a SMC reversed polarity (this is, a female jack), which i dont think exist, or perhaps as rare as a 10-32,
- An [SMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMA_connector) has a 1/4-36 thread, An [SSMA](http://www.amphenolrf.com/connectors/ssma.html) has a 10-36 thread, and the [SMB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMB_connector) no thread at all :),
- CDInt sells both [10-32 to SMA](https://www.cdint.com/catalog/category/Cables/10-32/to+SMA) and [10-32 to SMC](https://www.cdint.com/catalog/category/Cables/10-32/to+SMC/RG174) cables.....!,
- The device shows a female jack.

So i should finally purchase a 10-32?

[image]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you link the drawing?

Comment: My question is because pasternack sells both the SMC and the 10-32!!, so thats why i was confused.

Comment: ... Also for reference/curiosity an SMB connector is a push fit connector [Like this image](http://coaxplanet.com/Portals/2/SMB%20Jack%20and%20Plug%20with%20ID.jpg)

Comment: you deleted your answer, i was going to mark it :).

Comment: My answer was incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10-32unf and SMC are not compatible:

1. on the 10-32unf male = a nut + a central pin
2. on the 10-32unf female = a screw + a central hole
3. on the smc female (called plug) = a nut + a central hole
4. on the smc male (called receptacle) = a screw + a central pin

your sensor : electrical connector is a 10-32unf female

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation...